# How to claim role for HttpContext.User.IsInRole method check in integration test?

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, httpcontext, active-directory-group, role-base-authorization

I have following code for integration test

**TestAuthenticationHandler**

This handler is setting up the Test user named John Doe

```
public class TestAuthenticationSchemeOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
}

public class TestAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<TestAuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public TestAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<TestAuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) 
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim("MemberId", Options.Role),
            new Claim("MemberForename", "John"),
            new Claim("MemberSurname", "Doe")
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "Test");

        var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

**Test method**

This method is using the handler above to register the user and it also assign an Admin role

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("/home/index")]
public async Task GetServerSideRenderedPage_ReturnsOk(string url)
{
    // Arrange
    HttpClient client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddAuthentication("Test")
                    .AddScheme<TestAuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthenticationHandler>("Test", 
                        options => options.Role = "Admin");
        });
    }).CreateClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Test");

    // Act
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    Assert.NotNull(response.Content);
    Assert.Equal("text/html", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);
    Assert.True(response.Content.Headers.ContentLength > 0);
}
```

**Startup.cs**

Enabling authentication (No need for this in production)

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

**Controller action I need to test**

In production `HttpContext` is NOT NULL, but in test it is NULL. So I had to add `IHttpContextAccessor` which is populated via `AuthenticationHandler` (`HttpContext` is still NULL, but `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` is OK)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var allowed = _httpContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");

        return View();
    }
}
```

The issue I am facing is that `allowed` property is `false`, but I claimed the Admin role to the user.

[image]

In production it works because the app is running on the IIS server and the Admin role (named differently in the production) is domain security group. So the `HttpContext` is checking if the connected user is member of domain group, but I don't know how to fake/mock the `IsInRole()` method in the test. Do I have to add some additional claims in the `TestAuthenticationHandler`?

The settings described here works when using `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` attribute but I also need to use the `IsInRole()` method.

Do you have any idea?

**Solution**

The missing part here was specific role claim

```
var claims = new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Options.Role), // <-- this line was missing
    new Claim("MemberId", Options.Role),
    new Claim("MemberForename", "John"),
    new Claim("MemberSurname", "Doe")
};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `IsInRole` is the final point you can override to mock it, but there are earlier points for you to mock, here the user's roles. Why can't you mock that instead?

Comment: @King Kong: I don't understand, can you please provide an example? Do you mean to replace `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` middleware in `ConfigureTestServices` somehow? Or how do you mean to mock user's role? This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: where did you mock this `HttpContext.User`? just add claims of role for it there and it should work.

Comment: I am claiming the role in the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method, how can I claim the roles to `HttpContext.User` directly?

Comment: I think you should mock it so that it's much like the real scenario (hence integration test). But if you want to overwrite the value directly, try this `(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));` - the `User.Identity` is `IIdentity` but usually it should be a `ClaimsIdentity` (which is built from a set of claims).

Comment: It is working now! Thank you, you are a genius :-) I was also thinking if this is a right approach, because I have to use `app.UseAthentication()` middleware in the `setup.cs` to make the tests work... but it is only solution I found for now. I do know how to mock `HttpContext` via `Moq` but I don't know how to register this mock in the `WebApplicationFactory`?  Do you know some trick or what solution do you have in mind?

Comment: actually I'm not familiar with mocking framework because many projects I've worked on did not even have test projects :) - we usually use only human testers. It's just a mess but it's the environment we have to accept. I think it's not hard, but you need to read the references as well as sample code for mocking in specific scenarios to apply in your projects.